# What should I be using for an XML parser in my Android App?

Tags: android, xml, dom, sax, xmlpullparser

I want to create an App that uses a potentially large xml file. It will also modify and ideally be able to traverse in reverse.

I know there is SAX, DOM, and the XML pull parser. The pull parser is out, unless I spend memory on creating my own tree of objects which does not seem feasible.
That leaves SAX and DOM unless there is another parser out there that can do what I want. Highly improbable, I know.
 Yes, I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498616/which-xml-parser-should-i-use-for-android
Thoughts on having tree like usability without having to use DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options when it comes to parsing XML. But it depends on your own requirements that which parser you can use when. For that you need to know the basic differences between the parser. Here is some basic information i have provided.

**SAX** parser is one where your code is notified as the parser walks through the XML tree,
and you are responsible for keeping track of state and constructing any objects you might want to keep track of the data as the parser marches through.

**DOM** parser reads the entire document and builds up an in-memory representation that you can query for different elements. Often, you can even construct XPath queries to pull out particular pieces.

And as you said you are having large file and also if you want faster performance i suggest that you should use StAX parser. Here is [link](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) for that.

Hope this will help you...

Also refer this [link](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~epontell/courses/XML/material/xmlparsers.html#q1).

Answer (score 0):

DOM is better for most of the cases where it will load all the XML at a time. But If the XML size is very big then we should go for SAX parser where it will read for the tag from the start of the XML every time.

If the XML is really big then it is better to filter from the server end by sending the requirements in the request or else we can go for pagination which is suggestible.